# Using a parameterless controller constructor with Ninject?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject, elmah

I'm using Ninject for dependency injection in my application. Here's an example of one of my controllers:

```
public class DepartmentsController : Controller
{
    private IDepartmentsRepository departmentsRepository;

    public DepartmentsController(IDepartmentsRepository departmentsRepository)
    {
        this.departmentsRepository = departmentsRepository;
    }

    ...
}
```

I'm also trying to follow [this tutorial](http://dotnetdarren.wordpress.com/2010/07/27/logging-on-mvc-part-1/) to use ELMAH in an MVC application. The idea is to use a custom controller factory to handle errors from every controller. You then set the controller factory to the custom one in the global.asax.cs file.

The only problem is that it is expecting a parameterless constructor in each controller, which I can't do (that I know of) with dependency injection with Ninject.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using MVC3, you should ignore the part about the Controller Factory and use Global Filters to apply the custom attribute to each controller.

If you aren't using v3 yet and you can modify their code to inherit from the Ninject Controller factory.